# How to set background for QGraphicsSimpleTextItem (Qt C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have added to my `QGraphicsScene` a `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`, but just a simple text is unreadable of current background. Therefore I'd like to set background color of the `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`, but... there is no such method. What's the simplest solution?

Comment: Are you trying to change the background of the text item or of your whole scene?

Comment: The background of the text item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the simplest solution is to use `QGraphicsTextItem` instead of `QGraphicsSimpleTextIem` and to call `setHtml()` in the constructor, for example:

```
this->setHtml(QString("<div style='background-color: #ffff00;'>") + text + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the background of your whole scene:

```
myScene->setBackgroundBrush( Qt::red );
```

Or if you want to change the background of just your text item, you'll probably have to subclass `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` and override the `paint()` method.

```
class MyTextItem : public QGraphicsSimpleTextIem {
    public:
        void paint( QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget=0 )
        {
            painter->setBrush( Qt::red );
            painter->drawRect( boundingRect() );
            QGraphicsSimpleTextItem::paint( painter, option, widget );
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can access the background color.

```
QPalette currentPalette = myGraphicScene.palette();

// Set a new color for the background, use QPalette::Window
// as QPalette::Background is obsolete.
currentPalette.setColor( QPalette::Window, Qt::red );

// Set the palette.
myGraphicScene.setPalette( currentPalette );
```

Comment: I wanted to change the QGraphicsSimpleTextItem's background, not the whole scene.